# Undefined reference to GLEW functions when linking GLEW's static binary with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, mingw-w64, glew

## Problem

`glew32s.lib` is not linking correctly with the main executable. When building with MakeFile given by CMake, an error occurs stating that I have an undefined reference to `glewInit()`.

> CMakeFiles\NoGameEngine.dir/objects.a(window.cpp.obj):window.cpp:(.text+0x15d): undefined reference to `glewInit'

However in my top-level `CMakeLists.txt` I have linked the `glew32s.lib` through:

```
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/glew32s.lib)
```

I am completely clueless to why I am getting this undefined reference error. Note I have also declared the compile option `-DGLEW_STATIC`.

## What I have tried

Using another way to link the library:

```
target_link_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Dependencies)
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE glew32s.lib)
```

However I get the following errors:

> C:/MinGW64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~4/C__~1/Projects/GAMEPR~1/NOGAME~1/DEPEND~1/glew32s.lib when
> searching for -lglew32s
> C:/MinGW64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~4/C__~1/Projects/GAMEPR~1/NOGAME~1/DEPEND~1/glew32s.lib when
> searching for -lglew32s
> C:/MinGW64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~4/C__~1/Projects/GAMEPR~1/NOGAME~1/DEPEND~1\glew32s.lib when
> searching for -lglew32s
> C:/MinGW64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglew32s

## Resources

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23.)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(SourceFiles-Core
    NoGameEngine-core/src/main.cpp
    NoGameEngine-core/src/graphics/window.cpp
)
set(includeFiles-Core NoGameEngine-core/include)
set (includeFiles-Depend Dependencies/include)
add_compile_options(-DGLEW_STATIC)

find_package( OpenGL REQUIRED )

if (OPENGL_FOUND)
  MESSAGE("OpenGL Correctly Found")
else (OPENGL_FOUND)
  MESSAGE("OpenGL environment missing")
endif()

project(NoGameEngine)


include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${includeFiles-Core} ${includeFiles-Depend})

set( GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL  "GLFW lib only" )
set( GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE BOOL  "GLFW lib only" )

add_subdirectory( Dependencies/GLFW )

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SourceFiles-Core})
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} glfw)
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/glew32s.lib)
```

Directory Hierarchy:

Root:

- build
- Dependencies

  - GLFW
  - include

    - GL
  - glew32s.lib
- NoGameEngine-core

  - include
  - src
- CMakeLists.txt

Comment: MinGW is supposed to use `.a`, not `.lib`. `.lib` is for MSVC.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How do I get the `.a` version of glew? I tried searching but couldn't find any.

Comment: Build it yourself. Or just add `glew.c` as a part of your source code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How do I build it myself with CMake? I have researched and looked up a lot of things however still couldn't get a single clue.

Comment: Check [their readme](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew#build). It seems CMake is not their preferred way of building.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I downloaded the source files and typed in their cmake command which was `cmake ./cmake`, however I get promoted with this error `CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242329/discussion-between-isythnic-and-holyblackcat).